css keyframe animation doesnt work on ios chrome safari
.aboutme_secondgrid {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.aboutme_img img {
  transform: scale(.8);
  -webkit-transform: scale(.8);
  opacity: 0;
  height: 600px;
  animation: fade-in linear forwards;
  -webkit-animation: fade-in linear forwards;
  animation-timeline: view();
  animation-range-start: cover 100px;
  animation-range-end: 700px;
}

@keyframes fade-in {
  to {
    transform: scale(1);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade-in {
  to {
    transform: scale(1);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
  .aboutme_img img {
    transform: scale(.5);
    -webkit-transform: scale(.5);
    height: 300px;
    animation-range-end: 300px;
  }

i tryed a lot of things with webkit i asked chatgpt i change the scale: 0.8 to transform: scale(.8) i dont know what else to do! i just change everyting i can to webkit and still cant find it sorry if its easy mistake but i cant find it!

the  .aboutme_img img {
transform: scale(.5);
-webkit-transform: scale(.5);
height: 300px;
animation-range-end: 300px;
} is for media for phones

forwards is not a valid direction for animation. Try using normal. See the MDN docs for all valid values

Please create a runnable snippet so we can easily see for ourselves on IOS. Also please describe what ‘doesn’t work’ means.

@jla I can’t see where they have tried to set forwards incorrectly.

animation-range-… is not supported on IOS or FF. see https://caniuse.com/?search=animation-range-
